# no puedo crear el archivo .htaccess en ubuntu en el servidor local

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu

tengo los permisos para crear archivos en /var/www pero en una plantilla de wordpress no consigo crear el archivo .htaccess para poder configurar los enlaces permanentes de wordpress.

he seguido este tutorial:

1. Habilitar mod_rewrite con el siguiente comando:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   ```
2. Abrir el archivo:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
3. Descomentar la linea (remueve el simbolo #)

   ```
   AccessFileName .htaccess
   ```
4. Encuentra la siguiente sección

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

   Nota: la sección anterior también la puedes encontrar en el archivo:
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
5. Reemplaza “None” por “All” :

   ```
   AllowOverride All
   ```
6. Reinicia el servicio de Apache

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

pero cuando con sudo nano .htaccess
creo el archivo y le meto la configuracion que me da wordpress, no se me crea el archivo dentro de wordpress.

Comment: 1.- Cuando usas `sudo nano` para crear el `.htaccess` y lo editas. ¿Lo guardas al terminar? Creo recordar que era `Crtl+O` para guardar y `Ctrl+Z` para salir del editor. 2.- Cuando te refieres a _dentro de wordpress_ ¿que es exactamente?  ¿el directorio raíz de la instalación?

Comment: si para guardarlo el es crt + o, tenia la duda de si se creaba el htaccess dentro de la carpeta de la plantilla o del directorio principal de wordpress pero no puedo crear el archivo. tengo los permisos con chmod 777 /var/www ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: El archivo que editas, mejor dicho que creas, se guarda en la ruta donde los creas si no especificas otra. Por ejemplo, si el directorio raíz de `wp`es `/var/www` tienes dos opciones: 1.- `sudo nano /var/www/.htaccess` para crearlo independientemente de donde te encuentres. 2.- `cd /var/www` para acceder al directorio y `sudo nano .htaccess` para crearlo en el directorio donde estás. Lo editas y lo guardas.

Comment: no puedo crear el archivo .htaccess. en ningun directorio del servidor local. el apache2.conf lo modifique ya, puedo copiar archivos al directorio www pero el htaccess no puedo.

Comment: ¿Por  qué decís que no lo crea (no lo ves en un `ls`)?¿nano te informa algún tipo de error? Podrías agregarlo a tu pregunta.

Comment: si puedo crearlo. solo que no podia verlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Linux/Unix los ficheros que empiezan por un punto son 'ocultos'. No se ven con un 'ls' simple. Debes hacer un 'ls -a' para incluirlos en la lista